# rust lifetime &'a T

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am a beginner of rust, nowdays I have read the  content of lifetime;
and I wonder that for &'a T, dose it mean the value of T having a lifetime of 'a or the  Reference variable has a lifetime of 'a?

Answer (score 4):

Don't think of it as **having a lifetime**, think of it more as **requiring a lifetime**.

`&'a T` means *"A reference to a type T that is guaranteed to be valid for at least `'a`"*.

Neither `T` nor the variable that stores the reference '*have the lifetime* `'a`'. Instead, a variable is '*required to be available for at least* `'a`' to be referenced by that.

That's at least how my brain thinks about it, and it worked out pretty well so far.

---

A couple more details:

- `&'static T` - A reference to a `T` that has no restrictions on how long it can be borrowed; therefore it can be stored in structs without lifetime restrictions.
- `&'a T` - A reference to a `T` that is temporary and has to released at some point. If you store this in a struct, that struct will carry over the lifetime `T`.
- `T where T: 'static` or any struct that doesn't have a lifetime annotation - An owned object that doesn't depend on anything. It doesn't borrow anything and it can be freely stored in all other structs
- `T where T: 'a` - An owned object that internally stores a reference with a lifetime. This means this object has lifetime restrictions and every other object that this gets stored in needs to be annotated with a lifetime as well, just like when storing a `&'a T`.

To sum up, a "lifetime annotation" does not specify how long an object lives, but what other objects an object **depends on**. It's all part of the borrow checker.

So I now hope with this explanation that you can see why, in your original `&'a T` example, it isn't the `T` that has the lifetime `'a`, nor is it the variable that stores the reference. It's the reference itself that **requires** the lifetime `'a`. It's the way for the compiler to keep track of whether objects that depend on each other get released in the right order.

---

Finally, here a little example:

```rust
struct MyRefStruct<'a, T>(&'a T);

fn main() {
    {
        // K lives for some amount of time
        let k = String::from("k");

        // k_ref also lives for some amount of time.
        let k_ref = MyRefStruct(&k);

        // Let's do something with k_ref
        println!("{}", k_ref.0);

        // Here, first k_ref and then k get released.
        // This means, the lifetime `'a` of `k_ref` is shorter than the lifetime of `k`,
        // and everything is fine.
    }

    {
        let create_k2_ref = || {
            // K lives for the duration of this closure
            let k2 = String::from("k2");

            // k2_ref also lives for some amount of time.
            // The lifetime 'a contains the annotation that
            // MyRefStruct borrows `k2`.
            let k2_ref = MyRefStruct(&k2);

            // This is where the compiler complains: k2_ref gets returned.
            // Its 'a lifetime annotation, however, specifies that it borrows k2,
            // and returning it from this function would cause it to outlive its
            // borrowed value.
            k2_ref
        };

        let k2_ref = create_k2_ref();
        println!("{}", k2_ref.0);
    }
}
```

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `k2`
  --> src/main.rs:33:13
   |
27 |             let k2_ref = MyRefStruct(&k2);
   |                                      --- `k2` is borrowed here
...
33 |             k2_ref
   |             ^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

Note how specific the error message is. This is only possible due to the `'a` lifetime annotation, that carries all that information.

**Disclaimer:** I'm quite certain that this explanation is heavily simplified and slightly inaccurate compared to how it is actually implemented in the compiler.

Comment: I'm sure my explanation is technically very handwavy, but that's how it makes sense to me and so far it worked for me :) please someone correct me if there is something seriously wrong with my explanation.

Comment: I  am trying to understand the lifetime in this way, and I think that's right, which help me understood some code.

Comment: And I'm a little confused about automatic deref and ref. Can you help me.

Comment: I have open a new question.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example on `T: 'a`? There are few old examples (from 2014 or earlier) I see, but those (in 2023) compile without `T: 'a` requirement. So I have not seen example which compiles only if `T: 'a` is used, else it does not.

Comment: @Nawaz I'm not sure to be honest, I just tried to explain what they are. It's probably something like [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-elision.html) which makes them unnecessary in certain situations.

Comment: @Finomnis: OK. Maybe it's lifetime-elision. But I'm searching for example which compiles only if `T: 'a` is used (else it does not). I have not found any.

Comment: @Nawaz I don't know any right now. I've absolutely encountered them in the past, but I can't remember/reconstruct any of them of the top of my head right now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, one thing you should know is that borrow checker by default always assigns lifetime to parameters or variables in a scope to check various rules. These lifetimes are implicit which means you don't see them, but they exist.

Coming to your question, think like you haven't specified any lifetime like `'a` to type T. Then, in case of function parameters your code will look like `foo: &T`. This means that it is a reference of type T. What you are doing by adding `'a` is denoting the lifetime of `&T` (read as reference of type T). Nothing changes in your code apart from the fact that you decided to label the lifetime of parameter as `'a`.

In addition to this explanation, I highly recommend reading the [documentation on lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html).